# jQuery Autoresize plugin won't work on textarea within form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a textarea within a form element and I want it to auto-resize with this jquery plugin, but it won't work when I have it in a form that has an id. This is the form,

```
<form method="post" action="index.php" id="Form">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="input-group">
            <textarea cols="150" rows="1" style="resize: none;" placeholder="Comment..." class="form-control" type="text" id="commentBox1" name="comment"></textarea>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" id="hidden" value="'.$statusID.'" name="sID">
    </fieldset>
    <input class="Link LButton" type="submit" value="Add comment" name="sComment" />
</form>
```

The textarea will resize if the form doesn't have an ID, but if it does then it won't.

Answer (score 0):

Using the **jQuery** Autoresize plugin from: https://github.com/jackmoore/autosize and using

```
$('textarea').autosize();
```

Works for **me. MacOS Chrome.**

Which autoresize library are you using? Also your code didn't include a call to initialize the plugin with the **textarea** field. Please include your relevant **JavaScript** code also ?